# BeautifulSoup Tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I wanna print in the format of Certificates[h3 tag] - then the table under it 
then other documents[h3] -then table under it .
But with bs4 I am able to find these text values separately and not together in a format.
I'm a newbie when it comes to bs4.
The page link is - https://www.zaubacorp.com/documents/KAKDA/U01122MP1985PTC002857
Also, my code to find them separately is

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup=make_soup
("https://www.zaubacorp.com/documents/KAKDA/U01122MP1985PTC002857)
soup.prettify()
divs =soup.findAll("td", {"class" :"tab-tc-2"})
divs
soup.findAll("td")
soup.findAll('h3',{'class':'pull-left'})
date = [i.get_text() for i in soup.findAll('td',{"class" :"tab-tc-1"})]
date
header = [i.get_text() for i in soup.findAll('h3',{'class':'pull-left'})]
header
soup.findAll('h3',{'class':'pull-left'})
import pandas as pd
data=pd.DataFrame({"Date":date,"Certificates":Certi})
data
data
```

Comment: All i want is that there is a proper format to this scraping - The header then the table under it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will pandas read_html do?

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('https://www.zaubacorp.com/documents/KAKDA/U01122MP1985PTC002857')
for table in tables:
    print(table)
```

---

**With headers:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/documents/KAKDA/U01122MP1985PTC002857'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(res.content,'lxml')
headers = [header.text for header in soup.select('h3.pull-left')]
tables = pd.read_html(url)
items = zip(headers,tables)
for header, table in items:
    print(header)
    print(table)
```

Comment: Wow @Qharr . This will definitely do thank u so much .Can u just explain me that how pd.read html helped whereas html parser didnt

Comment: Also if i want to transfer this data to csv how can i do that ?